# How can this circuit be solved with the node method?

Tags: current, kirchhoffs-laws, nodal-analysis

I tried to solve this using the node method and it yields 0 on Mathematica, which I believe isn't correct. I'm trying to solve I1 first.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHsd7L.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

These are my equations:

[image: Node equations]

Thanks!

Comment: search https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=kvl+kcl+nodal and dont give up

Comment: Can you please point to me where am I doing something wrong? O something like that?

Comment: I'm actually trying to make this exercise from a set of problems I found. I wasn't being mean sir, sorry if you felt it like that.

Comment: these answers are everywhere if you learn how to search.. eg https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/229619/nodal-analysis-how-to-determine-high-and-low-potential-for-current

Comment: Thanks for the link but this isn't KVL, KCL.

Comment: Wouldn't \$I_1=\frac{V_1-V_2}{R_1}\$? Just curious? The current in \$V_1\$ must be the same as the current in \$R_1\$, yes?

Comment: Several methods exist: KVL, KCL, Nodal (I=Δv/R), Norton/Thevenin conversion, and mesh Current, supernodes. All on Wiki

Comment: @jonk Ohhh. Never thought of that. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a problem with your work is that you've defined \$I_1\$ as a tautology. Of course \$2\cdot I_1\$ can be defined the way you wrote it. But it doesn't add any information to the problem. It simply re-states things.

Here's a way to write it:

$$\begin{align*}
I_1&=\frac{V_1-V_2}{R_1}\\\\
\frac{V_2}{R_1}+\frac{V_2}{R_2}+\frac{V_2}{R_3}&=\frac{V_1}{R_1}+\frac{V_3}{R_2}+\frac{V_4}{R_3}\\\\
\frac{V_3}{R_2}+\frac{V_3}{R_4}+\frac{V_3}{R_5}&=\frac{V_2}{R_2}+\frac{V_4}{R_4}+\frac{V_5}{R_5}\\\\
\frac{V_4}{R_3}+\frac{V_4}{R_4}+2\cdot I_1&=\frac{V_2}{R_3}+\frac{V_3}{R_4}\\\\
\frac{V_5}{R_5}+\frac{V_5}{R_6}&=2\cdot I_1 + \frac{V_3}{R_5}+\frac{0\:\text{V}}{R_6}
\end{align*}$$

You should be able to solve for the five unknowns, \$V_2\$, \$V_3\$, \$V_4\$, \$V_5\$, and \$I_1\$ given the knowns (which includes \$V_1\$.)

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your question is illustrated as follows.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The following link is the onlinne calcualtor used to solve the equations:
http://math.bd.psu.edu/~jpp4/finitemath/4x4solver.html

If your results differ from those calulated, please indicate where and I will overview it.